# How to pass state value from form to its child modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popup, react-modal

I am new to React and I'm not sure what would be the best approach to take.

I have a modal component to be displayed once the user fills out the values inside the form and click on **Preview Voucher** to print those values inside the modal.

I tried this code and below I have the **Preview Voucher** component with a constructor and events.

```
// PreviewVoucher.js
class PreviewVoucher extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      voucherNumber: "0",
      //
      addModalShow: false
    };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSelectChange = this.handleSelectChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(e) {
    const target = e.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    const inputName = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [inputName]: value
    });
  }

  handleSelectChange(e) {
    this.setState({ labelSize: e.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

And I want to render this form on the page that has a child component **Modal Voucher**

```js
// PreviewVoucher.js
  render() {
    let addModalClose = () => this.setState({ addModalShow: false });
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <p>Number of vouchers to create:</p>
          <input
            min="0"
            type="number"
            name="voucherNumber"
            value={this.state.voucherNumber}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <h4>Message:</h4>
          <p>Some message</p>
          <ButtonToolbar>
            <Button onClick={() => this.setState({ addModalShow: true })}>
              Preview Voucher
            </Button>
            <ModalVoucher
              show={this.state.addModalShow}
              onHide={addModalClose}
            />
          </ButtonToolbar>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Create voucher" />
      </form>
    );
  }
```

And this is the child component - **Modal Voucher** that would contain some text and would like to display the dynamic values from the **Preview Voucher** component inside the < Modal Body >.

```js
// ModalVoucher.js
class ModalVoucher extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        {...this.props}
        size="lg"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
            Voucher preview
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <div>{/* update code here */}</div>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you tell us what the problem actually is with your code?

Comment: Hi danaa, welcome to StackOverflow! When posting a question, asking something specific makes it easier for others to answer. Is there something that you would like this code to do that it isn't doing?

Comment: Hi, so the code is working without receiving any errors, I just don't know how to display the form values inside the modal body. The constructor assigns the initial this.state (voucherNumber: "0") and when the user will put 1 in the input the modal body should display that onSubmit. I hope it makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Okay, it seems like your question is how to pass state values from a form to its child, so that they will be rendered within the child? (ModalVoucher is a child of PreviewVoucher). If so, it would be helpful if you included the minimum amount of code that shows that problem :)

Comment: What are you using as your Modal library? I am looking at `react-modal`, but it doesn't have some of the components you are using, like `Modal.Header` or `Modal.Title`. Are you using `react-bootstrap-modal` version 3? https://react-bootstrap-v3.netlify.app/components/modal/

Comment: I am using react bootstrap: https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/getting-started/introduction

Comment: @JuanCaicedo Many thanks!!

Comment: @danaa you're welcome! If my answer was helpful, it would be great if you'd set it as the official answer. It can also help if you edit the question to reflect the problem the way you understand it now, that way anyone who reads it in the future will understand it more easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to render parent's state within child component

You will need to pass the state value from `PreviewVoucher` into its child `ModalVoucher` as a prop.

```js
// PreviewVoucher.js
render() {
  <ModalVoucher
    show={this.state.addModalShow}
    onHide={addModalClose}
    voucherNumber={this.state.voucherNumber}
  />
}
```

Then use it inside of `ModalVoucher`s `render` method.

```js
// ModalVoucher.js
render() {
  <Modal.Body>
    <div>{this.props.voucherNumber}</div>
  </Modal.Body>
}
```

I put together this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-surf-lhhkv) showing this in action.

### Other suggestions

After making this change, you might see this error in the console

```
Warning: React does not recognize the `voucherNumber` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `vouchernumber` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
```

This occurs because you are passing all the props directly into the Modal, which
the underlying library passes to a DOM element.

```
<Modal
  {...this.props}
```

Because of this, I think it is usually a bad idea to directly forward all props
and I prefer to pass specific props instead.

```js
<Modal
  show={this.props.show}
  onHide={this.props.onHide}
```